# Simple MySQL self join query, want to get ID column for every entry that is repeated

Tags: mysql, group-by, self-join

SQL Fiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28938/9

I have a table like this:

```
+------+----------+--------+
|  id  | group_id | letter |
+------+----------+--------+
|  1   | 44       | a      |
|  2   | 55       | a      |
|  3   | 44       | b      |
|  4   | 55       | c      |
|  5   | 44       | c      |
|  6   | 55       | d      |
+------+----------+--------+
```

And I want to select any letters that have a count of two or more plus both group_ids that have that letter. Here's the query I'm working on:

```
SELECT b.id AS idx, a.id AS idy, a.letter FROM (
  SELECT id, letter, COUNT(1) AS count
  FROM temp WHERE group_id = 55
  OR group_id = 44
  GROUP BY letter
) AS a
JOIN temp AS b ON a.letter = b.letter
WHERE a.count > 1
AND group_id = 55
```

Here's my desired results:

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| idx | idy | letter |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 2   | 1   | a      |
| 4   | 5   | c      |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

But unfortunately this is what I'm getting

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| idx | idy | letter |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 2   | 1   | a      |
| 4   | 4   | c      |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

How can I guarantee the IDs are in the correct column?

Thank you!

Comment: Run the query. They're column aliases.

Comment: if there are 3 records for 'a' what should be the result

Comment: @zod my desired result is in my question in a neat little table.

Comment: @RachelD did my updated query give the required result?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you want regarding layout, but it does return the 4 fields. Your query above isn't working because your inner query does not result in id #5. Modified query below does it but it feels hacky.

```
SELECT
      MAX(IF (b.group_id = 55, b.id, -1)) as idx,
      MAX(IF (b.group_id = 44, b.id, -1)) as idy,
      b.letter
FROM 
  temp b

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
      letter, group_id, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM temp WHERE group_id = 55
    OR group_id = 44
    GROUP BY letter
    HAVING count > 1
  ) a ON (b.letter = a.letter)

GROUP BY letter
```

Comment: I need both id's for the record. I changed the id column aliases from bid to idx and aid to idy to try and illustrate that.

Comment: The updated query works on SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28938/55), hope it helps. I figured out that idx means id_group_55, etc.